# adding rows in a 2d list

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is what I need to accomplish>>
We will pass in a 2 dimensional list of numbers.
You should
add up all the numbers in each row and output that number
output the grand total of all rows

Provided:

```
# Get our list from the command line arguments
import sys
numbers= sys.argv[1:]

# Convert the command line arguments into 2d list
for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
  numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')
```

My Code:

```
print(sum(numbers[i]) for i in range(0, len(numbers)))
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Can you explain what works and what doesn't? What errors do you get? Please make this an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Also, consider np.sum(arr, axis=1).

Answer (score 0):

The provided code expects you to run the code from a terminal in the format of:

```
python code.py 1,2,3 4,5,6 7,8,9
```

and then it will convert this into a `2d` list, so in our example, `numbers` would be:

```
[['1', '2', '3'],
 ['4', '5', '6'],
 ['7', '8', '9']]
```

---

So the problem is now reduced to getting the total sum of *all* the numbers (`1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9`).

This can be done in one line:

```
sum(sum(int(j) for j in i) for i in numbers)
```

which gives us the expected output of **`45`**.